# Create layers from GeoJSON data with QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geojson

I am wanting to pull some data from an OData endpoint, and create layers based on the content, with a Python script.

I have grabbed the data and formatted it, but can't find the correct function to create the geometry from it.

Data is structurally the same as [Sample GeoJSON](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/geojson.htm#:%7E:text=sets%20of%20features.-,Sample%20GeoJSON,-The%20following%20is)

Where I am stuck is the line

```
geometry = QgsGeometry.fromGeoJson(json.dumps(feature['geometry']))
```

as there is no ".fromGeoJSON" function.

Is there a function in another class, or do I need to convert to WKT or something else first?

Relevant code section below.

```
# Create a layer for each feature
for feature in layerData["features"]:
layer_name = f"Layer_{feature['properties']['anomaly']}"

# Create a memory layer with polygon geometry type
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:4326', layer_name, 'memory')

# Define fields based on properties
fields = QgsFields()
for key, value in feature['properties'].items():
    field = QgsField(key, QVariant.String)
    fields.append(field)

layer.dataProvider().addAttributes(fields)
layer.updateFields()

# Add the feature to the layer
print(feature['geometry']['coordinates'])
geometry = QgsGeometry.fromGeoJson(json.dumps(feature['geometry']))
new_feature = QgsFeature()
new_feature.setGeometry(geometry)

for key, value in feature['properties'].items():
    new_feature.setAttribute(key, value)

layer.dataProvider().addFeature(new_feature)

# Add the layer to the project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is  [QgsJsonUtils.geometryFromGeoJson](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsJsonUtils.html#qgis.core.QgsJsonUtils.geometryFromGeoJson). However, you should be able to save some lines of code by creating a vector layer directly from the GeoJSON string:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer(json.dumps(layerData), layer_name, 'memory')
```

Then, to create a separate layer for each feature you can use the Split Vector Layer algorithm `native:splitvectorlayer`, passing 'anomaly' as the field to split by.

Comment: The method "geometyFromGeoJson" is not present in my install (QGIS v3.32.2 & Python 3.9.5) despite it showing in the docs. The other alternative you suggested takes a file path as its first argument, AFIK there is no way to pass an object (or array of objects) directly.

Comment: No, the first argument is a JSON string, dumped from a JSON object. I've used it directly with a json http response and it works